# How to remove this straight line in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to remove this line see this below picture because when I write the index page content display upper side that is the issue

Index page:

[image: Image of Index Page]

Contact page:

[image: when I click on contact page]

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="row">
                    @Html.ActionLink("abc Technology fgh", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left:500px;">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tech", "Tech", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Career", "Career", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Nipos", "Nipos", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Nosm", "Nipos", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <div class="navbar-fixed-bottom" style="margin-left:45px;">
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - CopyRight@flt.com</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
Home Page
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

What is the issue which place to come this unnecessary straight line? and index page content is come to render body and not display proper render body content

I don't have an idea which place come to the straight line continuously I comment and comment code but not idea which place to come this straight line trying but not remove this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a horizontal rule, just remove the `<hr />` tag, under @RenderBody in _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```html
<hr/>
```

tag from the html.  it will create horizontal rule in the html